# Отчество от несклоняемых имён, оканчивающихся на -о и на -е

Tags: ономастика

Как образовать отчество от:

- Амброзио (Амброзиевич? Тогда отца будто бы звали Амброзий, не складно. Может, Амброзиович?)
- Хосе (Хосевич?)

Comment: *>> не складно.* Единственно верного ответа нет - как в паспорте будет написано, так и будет правильно. Да и не приспособлены русские отчества к нерусским именам, поэтому искать "складность" не приходится.

Comment: А паспорт причём? До 14 лет без отчества ходить предлагаете? В любом случае, при заполнении документов нужны языковые нормы, как бы криво это для русских ни звучало. Форум всё же о языке, а не о житейском опыте, так что давайте обходиться без "как напишут, так и будет".

Comment: А здесь действительно как напишут, так и будет. Вот пример попроще: скажем, от имени Никита отчества чаще всего Никитич и Никитична, но кто скажет, что Никитович – ошибка? Так в свидетельстве о рождении и в паспорте!

Answer (score 1):

Вы всё верно предположили. Но никакой не Амброзиович: Амброзиевич или Амброзьевич.

> Кристо́баль **Хозевич** Ху́нта — персонаж книг «Понедельник начинается в
>   субботу» и «Сказка о Тройке» (Аркадий и Борис Стругацкие). Заведующий
>   отделом Смысла Жизни в НИИЧАВО, доктор самых неожиданных наук.

У моей подруги, полуиспанки, папу звали Альберто. Так ей было не совсем приятно, что она ("как грузинка") получилась Альбертовна - от  Альберт.

Несклоняемость имён в русских отчествах пропадает.

Comment: Тогда получается .что по отчеству иногда невозможно восстановить имя отца? Амброзиевич и Амброзьевич приводят к мысли, что отца звали или Амброз, или Амброзий. Т.е. я никак не догадаюсь, что он был именно Амброзио? И ещё вопрос: значит, принцип такой: берётся некий "корень" имени, отрубается всё, что нельзя склонить, и потом приставляем приемлемый суффикс?

Comment: Да! Такова конвертация иноязычного в русский!